# Better way to retrieve an array of column values in Laravel?

Tags: php, sql, laravel

Often in Laravel projects I need to get an array of column values from a complex SQL query. At the moment I use the following approach, but is there a more elegant/simpler way to do it (ie. that uses less than the 5 different function calls below)?

```php
// Complex query that wouldn't make sense to use Eloquent or query builder for:
$sql = <<<SQL
    SELECT
        c.id
    FROM
        ...various joins / subqueries etc here
    SQL;
$ids = collect(DB::select(DB::raw($sql)))->pluck('id')->toArray();
```

Comment: Interesting question! Are stored procedures maybe a way to solve this? (with alle their disadvantages)

Comment: I can't think that using a stored procedure would alter the Laravel-specific code required (ie. the "collect", "select", "raw", "pluck", "toArray" bits).

Comment: It was not clear to me that was the part you had problems with. How about just a wrapper function in a Trait for this and use it when needed?